# Check input obj type against custom interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Is there a way to write a function in typescript like below. Where type T belongs to my custom interface.

```
checkType<T>(input):boolean{
   if(typeof input === T){
     return true;
   }
   else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

Actually I have 5 dropdowns and each dropdown gets bind to a different interface. On "selectionChange" event ( one event handler for all 5 dropdown), I have written below function and I am getting input as an json object which belongs to one of the interface,

```
public selectionChange(value: any): void {
    if(this.checkType<ICustomer>(value)){

      console.log("yes, this is a customer");

    }
```

but this is not working. can anyone suggest the better approach OR am I doing something wrong with the current approach.

Comment: why negative rating? please put comment to explain the reason for the same.

Comment: Not my doewnvote, but I think it a duplicate of the referenced question, if you feel that does not answer your question let me know and I can  reopen

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir : The link you mentioned require to pass an object of type T as well with the type name and input obj. I am , kind of , trying to avoid passing an empty object ( of type T) for each type. Can you please reopen this question.

Comment: This is also a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839597/typescript-extract-interface-members-only-possible

Comment: In short since interfaces don't exist at runtime you will need to create some extra structure to guide your check, there is no quick way to do this.

Comment: I see your point. I agree. Let me see, how I can do that. I will post my result here once I am done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use `keyof`

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the typescript at all.

Typescript provides you only the transpilation-time control and it never ever throws any error in runtime and it does not do any special-checks (you can look to that transpiled code, it is very similar to original). Application is then using pure javascript and it is behaving as this.

The `typeof` is javascript keyword and even with typescript it will work just as in pure javascript. What you need can be done by creating instance of some class, you can get proper check with `instanceof`. Or you can have just some method, that finds out, what type you have based on some keyword.

Comment: but I do not want to create a class.  and to use typeof on an interface will result "object" always.

Comment: @Akash - yea sorry, I wanted to write instanceof at the end. But there is no direct way how to do what you need - instances or your own function that checks something.

Comment: yeah, I am working on it but I do understand that currently TS does let what I am trying to do so will do some hack. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Akash - Exactly. Type conversions with `<NewType>` are only syntactic sugar, there is nothing in transpiled code. If you dont use `any` and you try to do type conversion, typescript checks that before transpiliation time and it stops you if the type conversations is not correct. But it has no control of what you have in `any`, so it lets you do that, but it does not do any real conversion in code. Think about typescript that it is something like more strict and advanced JSDoc