# How to retrieve properties from object by another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Lets suppose there is object with properties names:

```
let obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "O",
  "age": 10
}
```

Also we have custom type or intereface:

```
type UserCustom = { name: string, id: number}
interface IUserCustom { name: string; id: number; }
```

Then lets write method that takes initial `obj` as `T` and custom type as `U`:

```
public _reduce<U>(values: T[], output?: U) {
   return data; // (U / T)
}
```

I tried to get retrieve from initial `obj` only properties which are exist in `U`.

Result is:

```
let result = {
      "name": "O",
      "age": 10
   }
```

What is approach to use in TypeScript?

Comment: I need something like `Intersection Type` but not for fusion types.

Comment: You can use an approach similar to what is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839597/typescript-extract-interface-members-only-possible/50895613#50895613