# Is there a way to extract instance of interface using instance another interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have the following: interface C extends A, B. I get an instance of C, and I want to create an instance of B using it. I tried to use spread operator, but it didn't work (the typecheck fails during compilation). Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide us with a code example of what you've tried?

Comment: An instance of `C` *is* an instance of `B`.  My guess is that your actual question has something to do with copying an object keeping only certain keys, which requires a runtime list of keys from `B` you care about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript - extract interface members only - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839597/typescript-extract-interface-members-only-possible)