# Typescript convert data from API into specific type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need only few properties from the received object. Is it possible to map through received data and remove unnecessary properties using Typescript interface?

**Example of data:**

```
[
  0: {
    "original_language" : "en",
    "title" : "The First Title",
    "original_title" : "The First Original Title",
    "overview": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac suscipit nulla.",
    "release_date": "2022-05-04",
    "popularity": 9411.64
  },
  1: {
    "original_language" : "en",
    "title" : "The Second Title",
    "original_title" : "The Second Original Title",
    "overview": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac suscipit nulla.",
    "release_date": "2022-05-04",
    "popularity": 9411.64
  },
  2: {
    "original_language" : "es",
    "title" : "The Third Title",
    "original_title" : "The Third Original Title",
    "overview": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac suscipit nulla.",
    "release_date": "2022-05-04",
    "popularity": 9411.64
  }
]
```

**Desired object properties (Typescript Interface):**

```
interface IMovie {
  overview: string,
  release_date: Date,
  title: string
}
```

My attepmt to write **mapper function**:

```
const movieMapper = (movies: []): [IMovie] => {
  return movies.map(movie => <IMovie>movie);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - extract interface members only - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839597/typescript-extract-interface-members-only-possible)

Comment: Hi, for api data types handling, I've never found something as solid as io-ts ( https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/ ) which actually verifies at runtime that the received data complies to what is expected. It also guards and infers to the needed typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a two interfaces: for actual api response array items and desire items:

```js
interface MovieFull {
  original_language: string
  title: string
  original_title: string
  overview: string
  release_date: Date
  popularity: number
}

type Movie = Pick<MovieFull, 'overview' | 'release_date', 'title'>
```

You can have a `Movie` as a independent type, but it's rather to be dependent from original one so in case the `MovieFull` will change, `Movie` will also change.

Next you can perform mapping:

```js
const movieMapper = (movies: MovieFull[]): Movie[] => {
  return movies.map(movie => ({
    overview: movie.overview,
    release_date: movie.release_date,
    title: movie.title,
  }));
}
// or, using decostruction
const movieMapper = (movies: MovieFull[]): Movie[] => {
  return movies.map(({ overview, release_date, title }) => ({ overview, release_date, title }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is a tuple, not an array.

You can use object destructuring to pick the fields and map to a new object.

```
const movieMapper = (movies: any[]): IMovie[] => {
    return movies.map(({overview, release_date, title}) => ({ overview, release_date, title}));
}

console.log(movieMapper(movies))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) you could write this codec:

```
// Codec file
import * as t from 'io-ts'

export const movieCodec = t.type({
  overview: t.string,
  release_date: t.string, // check out custom codecs to get dates as JS Date objects on decoding
  title: t.string,
})

export const movieListCodec = t.array(movieCodec)
```

then when you receive the response, you can guard it with the codec

```
// where you get the response
fetch(someEndpoint)
  .then<unknown>(r => r.json())
  .then(movieCodecList.is)
  .then(verifiedResponse => {
    // verifiedResponse is correctly typed AND it has been actually verified at runtime
  })
```

I know this answer goes a bit beyond what you asked but keep in mind that runtime checking anything coming from outside your code is recommended!